# Join two vectors of maps by selected key and with preserving the order of elements

Tags: clojure

I have two vectors of maps like this:

1:

```
[{:id 54785214 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 1254561561 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 156156456 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 77897445 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 4848121 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 787897212 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 45478789 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 112315478 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 154847841 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 65698898 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}]
```

2:

```
[{:id 547485214 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 12545561561 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 1561456456 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 778927445 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 4848121 :field "hhh" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 7817897212 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 455478789 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 1123615478 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 1541847841 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}
{:id 656988898 :field "fff" :attributes [{:id 1 :field "ddd"}]}]
```

and a function to join these two vectors with merging maps with the same key (i choose :id):

```
(defn join-map-sets [set-a set-b by-key]
  (map #(apply merge %) (vals (group-by by-key (concat set-a set-b)))))
```

And after I apply this function to maps 1 and 2, the result is not ordered like in source maps. Preview of the first 3 maps of the result:

```
({:id 154847841, :field "fff", :attributes [{:id 1, :field "ddd"}]}
 {:id 1541847841, :field "fff", :attributes [{:id 1, :field "ddd"}]}
 {:id 656988898, :field "fff", :attributes [{:id 1, :field "ddd"}]})
```

And for the question: how to modify my function to always preserve the order of the maps? Just like concat does, but with replacing/merging duplicates.

ps. sorry for ugly example but for simple ones it's not showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way will be to use `distinct`:

```
(distinct (concat v1 v2))
```

will give you a lazy sequence with duplicates removed.
(`v1` and `v2` being your vectors..)

a `count` will prove that the duplicates are removed:

```
(count (distinct (concat v1 v2)))
```

*By the way, there are no duplicate `:id` in your code example, look carefully the id numbers do not match exactly.*

Comment: Thank you for answering, but your solution is not gonna work for my case. Maybe it is not clear from my question (sorry for that) but it is not guaranteed that :field or any other value in my maps from second vector will be identical with those from the first one - only :id must be unique, and the rest of the map body must be replaced with the values from the second map. (yes, i know there are no duplicate :id, I edited the post to include one, to be more represantative example)

Comment: I just tried your code (`join-map-sets`) with a simpler example and it does just what you are after (to my understanding), it merges the vectors, updates the maps that has a similar `:id` to the one in the second vector while keeping the order of the first vector, thus adding the maps with a new id last.

Comment: Here is a screenshot from exact example as in my question: https://image.prntscr.com/image/pGCYf8rhTSKq7ajR686xGA.png  It's from a http://clojurescript.net/ so you can test it yourself.

Comment: you are right...the online repl you link to does make a mess of it, It doesn't do it in `cider` or in `lein repl`, I suppose it is the difference between the JVM and Javascript. I will look further.

Comment: http://comp-phil.blogspot.com/2014/11/distinctly-preserving-order-in-clojure.html this blog post seems useful, but i can't seem to adjust this solution to my case. I managed to maintain correct order using this method, but map values are taken from the first vector and not copied from the second one.